# Any reason to use a json string in the MessageBody instead of individual attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I think using Message Attributes is the way to go. We only use 4 attributes and are worried that eventually we'll hit the 10 attribute limitation.

Is there any benefit to using MessageBody instead of individual attributes other than the 10 attribute limitation?

I believe `MessageBody` doesn't have a limit except for the total message size limit of 256 KB which is huge. Then again, a single attribute also has the same limit.

A better question is when to use one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of SQS Message attributes is that they are designed to be used as message metadata (like message category or message type of ) and not the message itself.

E.x. if your application supports both JSON and XML payloads types, then possibly you can put the payload type as one of the message attribute and when you fetch the message, then based on the payload type attribute you can choose if a XML message processor is to be used or a JSON processor. This is just an superficial example for explaining usage of body and attributes

The actual message payload should be given in body of SQS Message, ideally.

Following para is an extract from [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-attributes.html)

> Amazon SQS lets you include structured metadata (such as timestamps, geospatial data, signatures, and identifiers) with messages using message attributes. Each message can have up to 10 attributes. Message attributes are optional and separate from the message body (however, they are sent alongside it). Your consumer can use message attributes to handle a message in a particular way without having to process the message body first.